# onTap - detectTapGestures not working properly as clickable(s) with same code and state hoisting

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a method 'activity' which hosts a 'screen' and since state hoisting is cool, I did just that but with a problem.

While the code works perfectly (incrementing the value) using **Modifier.clickable**, the same code does not properly work using  **detectTapGestures::onTap** as can be observed through  **Log.d("ExampleScreen", "onClick Multi Count is $multiCount")**

```
@Composable
fun ExampleActivity() {
    var multiCount by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    Log.d("ExampleActivity", "Multi Count is $multiCount") //this works either way

    ExampleScreen(
        multiCount = multiCount,
        incrementMultiCount = {
            multiCount = ++multiCount
        }
    )
}

  @Composable
    fun ExampleScreen(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        multiCount: Int,
        incrementMultiCount: () -> Unit
    ) {
            Log.d("ExampleScreen", "Example Multi Count is $multiCount") //this works either way
            Column(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding()
            ) {
    
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(100.dp, 50.dp)
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer)
                        .clickable {//this works
                            incrementMultiCount()
                            Log.d("ExampleScreen", "onClick Multi Count is $multiCount")
                        }
           /*             .pointerInput(Unit) { //this does not work
                            detectTapGestures(
                                onTap = {
                                    incrementMultiCount()
                                    Log.d("ExampleScreen", "onClick Multi Count is $multiCount") //this stays 0
                                },
                                onLongPress = {
    
                                }
                            )
                        }*/, text = "Click to confirm"
                )
            }
    }
```

> Partially, it works the same **(incrementing works but not reading the
> value)** as shown in **logs defined in ExampleActivity** and **function body of
> ExampleScreen** but **doesn't** in the **onTapGesture**.

**If the remember value is directly in the ExampleScreen composable, onTap and clickable works perfectly** but not what I wanted.

Finally, **before suggesting I use what works,** I wanted to use detectTapGestures because I really **need the LongPress method for a secondary work**.

Plus I will really **appreciate an explanation since I thought both works the same**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wrap your callback in `rememberUpdatedState`, something like this:

```
val onTap: () -> Unit = {
    incrementMultiCount()
    Log.d("ExampleScreen", "onClick Multi Count is $multiCount")
}
val updatedOnTap = rememberUpdatedState(onTap)

detectTapGestures(onTap = { updatedOnTap.value.invoke() })
```

This is what `.clickable` modifier does with its `onClick` argument as well, you can see that in its source code. Explanation can be found in `rememberUpdatedState` documentation:

> `rememberUpdatedState` should be used when parameters or values computed during composition are referenced by a long-lived lambda or object expression. Recomposition will update the resulting `State` without recreating the long-lived lambda or object, allowing that object to persist without cancelling and resubscribing, or relaunching a long-lived operation that may be expensive or prohibitive to recreate and restart.

By the way, there is also `Modifier.combinedClickable` that can be used for long click detection.

Comment: I appreciate the explaination as well the other alternative you provided. They both worked. I will read more about it.

Comment: thanks for mentioning Modifier.combinedClickable